# Recovering RDP access to potentially compromised GCE Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I have a Windows 2008R2 server in GCE that is behaving oddly (may be compromised). I can no longer access it via RDP. When I reboot the machine and look at the serial console, I see at the very bottom after the boot sequence, that something called Credentials Manager runs and appears to delete or change some username/password. I suspect that this is what is changing the RDP password. (see image attached). On a normally running Windows VM, I do not see this in the trace.

````
GCE Agent started.
Starting AddressManager
Starting CredentialsManager
Credentials have changed. Updating...
Changing username...
Deleting old user...
Username or password was updated successfully.```
````

I have tried resetting or adding a new password using the metadata windows-startup-script-cmd = net user   but that does not seem to do anything.

What I get is an error message of the form:

```
Booting on date 05/05/2015 10:22:49
WARNING: Computer Name windows does not match Compute Engine Instance Name XXXXX.
Did you forget to run gcesysprep?
attributes/windows-startup-script-bat value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
attributes/windows-startup-script-ps1 value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
```

So the question is, how can I get into the machine to see what is happening? Is there a way that the GCE startup sequence could be changed to not call the credential manager to change the password or username?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is if you have a Gcloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/) installed, you can run the following command while that instance is running:

`gcloud compute instances decribe instance_name`

This will provide all the information about the instance and you will see a section called **MetaData** which will display the users and the passwords. Then you can try to remote in and remove any credentials setup in the Credentials Manager located in **Control Panel -> User Accounts**.

I hope this give you access to your VM